# URLError in Python

Tags: python, exception, error-handling

I am trying to understand if I can handle the following error in python.

So I have a program which repeatedly calls the following line:

```
candidate = urllib2.urlopen(absolute_path)
```

After running my program for some seconds, I turned off my `wifi` connection, and got the following error:

```
File "crawler.py", line 28, in urlQuery
  candidate = urllib2.urlopen(absolute_path)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
  return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
  response = self._open(req, data)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
'_open', req)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
  result = func(*args)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1214, in http_open
  return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1184, in do_open
  raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 65] No route to host>
```

Is there any way I can handle this error?

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you want to do when you get this Exception. You can use `try-except`, standard Python's exception handling technique.

```
try:
    candidate = urllib2.urlopen(absolute_path)
#except Exception as e: # catches any exception
except urllib2.URLError as e: # catches urllib2.URLError in e
    print ('WiFi connection perhaps lost !! Trying one more time...')
    try:
        candidate = urllib2.urlopen(absolute_path)
    except:
        print ('WiFi connection really lost !! Bailing out..')
        print (e) # print outs the exception message
```

Comment: @Andy - Just to show the standard way of catching any exception. Btw I modified to catch only `URLError`

Comment: So when I catch the exception, I want to again try to see if the url opens or not, and if it opens I want to return candidate. Could you please modify your answer to take care of this?

Comment: use a `try-except` inside the first except. Modified my answer